# Who will send the timer interrupt in Linux?

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel, interrupt

Here is my understanding of TIMER:

Jiffies - It holds the number of timer ticks/interrupts since the System Boot up
HZ      - Number of timer ticks per second

Real Time Clock (RTC) - is a hardware, which stores the absolute time. It is a non-volatile clock.
It is used by the Kernel to initialise the xtime kernel variable.

Question here is Kernel sets HZ with an intent to receive HZ number of timer interrupts in one second. Who is going to generate the interrupt here ? Is there any other hardware apart from RTC to do this or How it is done ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_interval_timer   http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/pit.htm

Comment: Read also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Comment: It happens at this function http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L1736

Comment: Thanks much !!! I had gone through the time(7) and PIT. After detailed walk through, PIT is the device on the board which is programmed to signal interrupts/timer ticks at each jiffi size time.
Please correct me if I am wrong here.